# How to pass a list whose names is not NULL to the arguments of do.call in r

Tags: r, do.call

When I try to pass a list whose names is not NULL, I get the following error from evaluating do.call: Error: argument "x" is missing, with no default. Is there another way to bypass the names of the list and access instead the actual elements within the list without setting the names to NULL?

```
# with NULL names, do.call runs
num_list <- list(1:10)

do.call(mean,num_list)

# without names being NULL, do.call fails
names(num_list) <- 'a'
do.call(mean,num_list)
```

Specifically, I'd like to pass the list to a function's ellipsis such as for raster::merge, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.3-7/topics/merge.

```
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(raster)

cities <- sf::st_read(system.file("vectors/cities.shp", package = "rgdal"))
birds <- sf::st_read(system.file("vectors/trin_inca_pl03.shp", package = "rgdal"))

sf_shapes <- list(cities, birds)

# without names works
sf_shape_extents = lapply(sf_shapes, raster::extent)
sf_max <- do.call(what = raster::merge, args = sf_shape_extents)

# with names does not
names(sf_shapes) <- c('cities', 'birds')
sf_shape_extents_names = lapply(sf_shapes, raster::extent)
sf_max_names <- do.call(what = raster::merge, args = sf_shape_extents)
```

Comment: `do.call(mean,list(num_list$a))` or `mean(num_list$a)`

Comment: (Apologies if I misunderstand do.call, I haven't used it very much.) When you give your list the name "a", `do.call` looks for an argument "a" in the function `mean`. If, for example, you gave the list the name "x" `do.call` would work as expected because `mean(x, ...)` has the argument "x". If you want a named list `do.call` might not be the function you're looking for.

Comment: Why do you want it to work with names? How do you want it to work on a list with names? Same way as on a list with no names or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either ensure that the names of the list being passed in corresponds to the parameters of the function, or that the list is unnamed and the position of the list elements corresponds to the position of the parameter in question.

```
names(num_list) <- 'x'
do.call(mean,num_list)
[1] 5.5

names(num_list) <- 'a'
do.call(mean,unname(num_list))
[1] 5.5
```

EDIT:

I do not see any structural change in your edited version. The error is because of the names since they do not correspond to the named parameters of the function. You are passing in named arguments and that will throw an error.
The question you need to ask yourself is **what are the parameter names of the function you intend to use?**
If the ellipsis of a function takes in unnamed parameters, then whether the passed in arguments are named or not, it does not matter. eg, the `paste` function in R:

```
a <- list(a="a",b=3,c="d");
do.call(paste,a)
[1] "a 3 d"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. What about in the case however of passing the list to an ellipsis? I'll update my question with a second reprex.

Comment: @ENIAC-6 just remove the names with the function `unname` even after the update, you still have to remove the names. Or give the names needed. Unless the function is position only or have no-named parameters. eg `a<- list(a="a",b=3,c="d");do.call(paste,a)`